# Redux saga doesn't execute after yield call

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

I have this deleteSkill handler. In this handler I'm calling some api to delete skill. ( yield call(utils.deleteSkill) ). Its calling the api successfully but after that nothing execute. The console statement after yield call doesn't output anything. I'm not able to figure out anything. 
Can anyone help me please?

```
import { takeLatest, delay, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga'
import { call, fork, put, race, take } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import * as ActionTypes from './../constants/actions'

/* Handlers */
function* fetchSkills(action) {
 try {
    const { data } = yield call(utils.fetchSkills, action)
    yield put({type: ActionTypes.SUCCESS_FETCH_SKILLS, data})
  } catch (e) {

  }
}

function* deleteSkill(action) {
 try {
    yield call(utils.deleteSkill, action.data) //doesn't execute after this 
    console.log('Hello') //won't execute
    yield put({type: ActionTypes.REQUEST_FETCH_SKILLS})
  } catch (e) {}
}

/* Watchers */
function* watchFetchSkills() {
 while (true) {
    yield* takeLatest(ActionTypes.REQUEST_FETCH_SKILLS, fetchSkills)
  }
}

function* watchDeleteSkill() {
  while (true) {
    yield* takeLatest(ActionTypes.REQUEST_DELETE_SKILL, deleteSkill)
  }
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
 yield [
    fork(watchFetchSkills),
    fork(watchDeleteSkill),
  ]
}
```

Comment: it would be useful to see the `utils.deleteSkill` function

Comment: `export function deleteSkill (data) {  
  return DELETE({  
    api: '${expertsAPI.skills}${data}/',  
    handleError: true  
  })  
    .then(json => json)  
}`

Comment: does your console output a warning like `deleteSkill was cancelled` ?

Comment: No it doesn't execute at all !

Comment: @VonD deleteSkill is executing fine.

Comment: @madhurgarg did u find a solution to your problem?? I am also facing a similar problem. thanks.

Comment: @TajveerSinghNijjar It's a very old question I don't even have access to that code.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it's because in your `function* watchFetchSkills()` and `function* watchDeleteSkill()`, the `yield` should not have an `*`.  It should just be `yield`.

Even though you're calling another generator function from 
`function* watchDeleteSkill()` it's actually calling `takeLatest`, which according to the source:

https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/5fa5d628a80bbb4bfe488288b3ed19b5396f4d14/src/internal/io.js#L164

Is not a generator function.  It's just a plain old function, which means `yield*` isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

de-structuring 'action' and passing only required arguments to "yield call(actionFunc, ...args)" might help.